# Using awk to calculate ram usage from /proc/meminfo

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk

I want to use awk only to calculate memory usage from /proc/meminfo file.
I tried to do `awk ‘NR==1 || NR==2 {print $2}` it prints the 2nd column in the first 2 lines ( **MemTotal** and **MemFree** ) but I want to output the difference.
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Why not use the `free` command? Adding `--kilo` flag will print the same values: `free --kilo`.
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/free.1.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
awk 'NR==1{T=$2} NR==2{F=$2; print(T-F); exit}' /proc/meminfo
```

Comment: My only critique of this solution is that it presumes that MemTotal and MemFree is always row 1 and 2 respectively. It might be safer to use pattern matching in case the presumption is false on some systems. I would do something like this:
`awk '/MemTotal|MemFree/ {sub("kB", "", $2); values[$1] = $2} END {print values["MemTotal:"] - values["MemFree:"]}'  /proc/meminfo`

Comment: @357up `sub("kB", "", $2)` is not necessary because kB is in the third field `$3`

Comment: @357up I totally see your point. I was trying to solve OP's request using code as close as possible to theirs without introducing extraneous, possibly confusing, features/niceties or error-checking.

Comment: The output of ‘top’ and ‘free’ is different, why is that ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:       11979236 kB
MemFree:         2118136 kB
MemAvailable:   10570620 kB
Buffers:           11436 kB
Cached:          8044856 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:          7245688 kB
....

$ awk '/MemTotal:/{t=$2} /MemFree:/{f=$2} t && f{print t-f; exit}' /proc/meminfo
9861496
```